# JavaScript append element to body dynamically and addEventListener to it

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, I'm Sri Lanka, and my english is not really good.

I have created change theme system using javascript. I want to add  `changeThemeControlPanel` to every pages. so i append it on document onload event. so it doesn't matter it's work well.

After I added `addEventListener` to it. it doesn't work.
So i want append `changeThemeControlPanel` to body and add `addEventListener` to it without using `onclick` option.
**if doesn't understand my english please see my code and Help me. Thanks.**

> i only want to append it and add click event to it without `onclick`

**My JavaScript is here**

```
var changeThemeControlPanel = '<div id="change-theme"><a href="javascript:;" class="dark">DARK</a><a href="javascript:;" class="light">LIGHT</a></div>';

function changeThemeTo(theme_value) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('THEME'); // remove old theme from session storage
    if (theme_value == 1) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("THEME", 'dark');
    } else if (theme_value == 0) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("THEME", 'light');
    }
    document.body.className = sessionStorage.getItem("THEME");
}

var themes = ['dark', 'light'];

themes.forEach(function (item) {
    var theme = document.querySelector("." + item);
    console.log(item);

    if (theme) {
        theme.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (item == "dark") {
                changeThemeTo(1);
            } else if (item == "light") {
                changeThemeTo(0);
            }
        });
    }

}, this);

window.onload = function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += changeThemeControlPanel;
    document.body.className = sessionStorage.getItem("THEME");
}
```

**HTML Code is here**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .dark {
        background-color: #191919;
        color: #EEEEEE;
    }
    .light {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        color: #191919;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i am not sure whether this is what you asked for. But from my understanding please read the following

`themes.forEach` executes before `window.onload` so the line `var theme = document.querySelector("." + item);` would be null or undefined. I hope you understand.

For your code to work, try

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += changeThemeControlPanel;
    var themes = ['dark', 'light'];

themes.forEach(function (item) {
    var theme = document.querySelector("." + item);
    console.log(item);

    if (theme) {
        theme.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (item == "dark") {
                changeThemeTo(1);
            } else if (item == "light") {
                changeThemeTo(0);
            }
        });
    }

}, this);
    document.body.className = sessionStorage.getItem("THEME");
}
```

In the above code first we append the div to body, then we run the querySelector so the element would be present and accessible by your script. You are trying to fetch an element before that element exist. i hope you understand.

Comment: Yeah i understand. Now it's work well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Assesment 2</title>
    <link   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assets\css\style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Assets\lib\jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Assets\lib\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">


        <!-- <button >Add </button>
        <button>Remove</button>
        <button>Add</button>
        <button>Remove</button>
        <button>Red</button>
        <button>Green</button>
        <button>Blue</button> -->



        <ul>

        </ul>
        <center>
        <div id="randomBackground" class="square">squares</div>
        <button id="Genrtecolors" class="genBtn">Generate</button>
        </center>


        <div>

                <button id="addBttn" class="addBtn" >Add </button>
                <button id="RemoveBttn" class="RemovBtn" >Remove</button>


                <ul id="ULlist">

                </ul>

                <button class="button button1">Green</button>
                <button class="button button2">Blue</button>
                <button class="button button3">Red</button>

        </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets\js\script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider adding some context to your answer to explain why your solution works.